# Floating Second Element Right w/o Specifying Width of First?

Tags: html, css, layout, css-float

(Apologies for the title. The problem is much more easily demonstrated than named.)

I have two elements: a content container (#content) and an ads container (#ads).  The content container will be on every page of a site.  The ads will be on some pages and are of a fixed width.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

    <style type="text/css" media="screen">

        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #container {
            width: 800px;
            border: 1px solid blue;
        }

        #ads {
            float: right;
            border: 1px solid lime;
        }

        .ad {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            background: gray;
        }

        #content {
            overflow: hidden;
            border: 1px solid red;
        }

    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="container">

        <ul id="ads">
            <li class="ad">Buy Coke</li>
            <li class="ad">No, Buy Pepsi!</li>
            <li class="ad">Coke bought more ad space</li>
        </ul>

        <div id="content">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

(Alright, I admit that this isn't *really* my code, but the content/ads simplification makes my question a lot more straightforward.)

What I have here is basically a perfect setup in that it allows for the #ads list to be removed, and the #content to naturally reflow to take up its space.  Furthermore, I have not specified the width of #content anywhere in the stylesheet.  This offers an extra degree of flexibility: the layout can be used with a container of any width.

But I'm a perfectionist; I don't want the ads to come before the content in source order.

My question: is there a way to accomplish this layout that satisfies the following requirements:

- #ads follows #content in the source
- Removing #ads from the source results in #content taking up the entire width of its parent (#container) without CSS changes
- The width of #content is not explicitly written into the CSS (i.e. The only change needed to make the page wider is to modify #container's width)

Comment: from the moment you didn't set width for content, isn't logical to take the empty space of ads when it's removed? It's the default way to do this

Comment: Second condition is tricky. Can't think of any way to do it. Except that it can be easily solved with relative/absolute positioning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you're not scared of css3 (basically meaning, you don't have to bother about ie) this is indeed possible:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <style>
        .container{display:-moz-box; -moz-box-orient:horizontal; width:500px; background:yellow;}
        .content{-moz-box-flex:1; background:red;}
        .ads{background:blue; width:100px;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>with ads:</p>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="content">content</div>
        <div class="ads">ads</div>
    </div>
    <p>without ads:</p>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="content">content</div>
    </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

this is firefox only, be sure to apply the corresponding vendor prefixes (-webkit-, -o-) for other browsers. to make this work in ie though there will be some javascript to write.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I should've specified, but no CSS3.

Answer (score 0):

requirements 1 & 3 are contradicting each other. if you want that #ads follows #content in the source and not provide width to #content then ads will be shown below the content and not in the right.since #content doesn't have width it will occupy full width of container. I think you need to give away with requirement 1.The way it is done now is absolutely fine.