# Container floating problem

Tags: html, css

[image: sketch]

Hey,
I have a big problem with my container-sketch. How can I realize this ? When I set the width from the two navigations (blue container) there are under the logo (red container). The two navigation will run across the screen, right next to the logo. If I resize the browser window, the two navigations should NOT slide under the logo. Has anybody a example for me ?

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>New</title>
    <style type="text/css">

        .logo {
            float: left;
            width: 260px;
            height: 50px;
            background: green;
        }

        .nav-main {
            background: red;
        }

        .nav-sub {
            background: blue;
        }

    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="header">
        <div class="logo">
            .logo
        </div>
        <div class="nav-main">
            .nav-main
        </div>
        <div class="nav-sub">
            .nav-sub
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5540485/how-to-make-an-inline-block-element-fill-the-remainder-of-the-line

Comment: I need DIV-Container and no Table-Layout :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.header{
 min-width:320px;  
}
```

[check example](http://jsfiddle.net/5Ppka/)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `width` to the `nav-main` and `nav-sub`

See http://jsbin.com/isuxu4 for a demo