# How to properly float two columns side by side with css

Tags: jquery, html, css, width, css-float

This is one of those things I learned a long time ago and never thought much about if I was actually doing it the *right* way.

Let's say we have a structure like so:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="sideBar"></div>
  <div id="mainContent"></div>
</div>
```

Let's also say that `wrapper` has a width of `600px`.

Should I float `sideBar` `left`, and `mainContent` `right`, or should I float them both `left`?

Additionally, if I set a fixed width for `sideBar` how can I make `mainContent` fill up the rest of the space similar to how a table works? If I set `mainContent` to `display:inline-block` and `width:100%` it moves down onto the next line :/

Note: In my specific scenario I do not want to use a table.

Comment: Do the columns have to be equal height?

Comment: @thirtydot, in this example, no.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You `display:block` along with `float:left` to float divs next to each other.

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/FhL4u/2/

To make mainContent fill up rest of the space if only the first div width is known then use percentages on both sideBar and mainContent ex: 20% 80% instead of using fixed width. otherwise you will need a JavaScript solution to achieve a cross browser compatibility.

### Check jQuery solution at http://jsfiddle.net/FhL4u/3/

Comment: Semi-related article: http://blog.mozilla.com/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/. Be careful because older browsers (like IE7 or Firefox 2) don't handle inline-block well. You can also just float your content and use backgrounds in wrapper elements to make it look like the columns are of equal height.

Comment: Some critique: you don't need jQuery (overkill..) to do this, see my answer. Also, whenever you use `display: inline-block`, you should at least mention the fact that it doesn't work in IE7 without hacks (see the article linked by @Guttsy). Lastly, the first demo doesn't (quote from question) `"fill up the rest of the space similar to how a table works"`. Edit: Also, you have `position:inline-block` - fix to `display: inline-block`.

Comment: I changed inline-block to block. Read comment above.

Comment: I see. Well, you might want to edit the first line of your answer, it's still talking about `inline-block`.

Comment: I feel like I'm picking on you now (sorry!), but: if you use `float: left` (or `right`..), then `display: block` is "automatically set". You don't need to explicitly add it.

Comment: The jquery solution doesnt seem to work with a width: 100% wrapper :(

Answer (score 6):

I'm modifying my answer from here: [How to make an inline-block element fill the remainder of the line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5540485/how-to-make-an-inline-block-element-fill-the-remainder-of-the-line/5587563#5587563)

- Only `#sideBar` is floated.
- You can't really tweak this technique to have equal height columns later on, so that's why I asked before answering. (well, you can, but you need to use a `background-image` for [faux columns](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/))

See: http://jsfiddle.net/qx32C/37/

```
#wrapper {
    overflow: hidden; /* clear the float */
}
#sideBar {
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
    background: #f0f
}
#mainContent {
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #ccc
}
```

---

[Why did I replace `margin-left: 100px` with `overflow: hidden` on `#mainContent`?](http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/#making-room-for-floats)

Comment: Margin-left s not a flexible solution.

Answer (score 1):

using float left or right is not important.
you have wrapper with the width of 600px.
when you using float for both sidebar and contain inside the wrapper, you must make sure that the width of sidebar and contain (including margin and padding) equal or less than 600px.
If not, the second element will be below the first one.
Hope this helps ^^

Answer (score 1):

use `display:flex` for two div floats side-by-side

```css
#wrapper {
    width: 600px;
    display: flex;
}
#sideBar {
    display: inline-flex;
    width: 25%;
}
#mainContent {
    width: 75%;
    flex: 1;
}
```