# Can't get CSS to replace a table (2-cells, right with width=1)

Tags: css, html-table, css-float

Yes, I know this seems like the same question yet again, but give me a chance...
I'm trying to create something similar to an http address box and "go" button:

[input box - width of whole window minus size of right button] [go button]

Very easy with a table (works with a `<form>` and input boxes too)

```
<table width="100%"><tr>
<tr>
<td>free text goes in here and takes as much space as available! free text goes in here and takes as much space as available!</td>
<td width="1"><a href="">GO</a></td>
</tr></table>
```

Before you answer, note that critical to a CSS "success" is NOT to set the width of the GO button as fixed! I know how to do it in CSS with a fixed width float right, but ... This would means that if the "GO" text changes to "RUN" or the font changes, I've to manually re-set the width of the fixed right part. That makes the whole point of CSS (IMNSHO) pointless, esp. if a table is smart enough to do this.

Comment: If you don't specify the width of a floated element it will take the space it needs to display its contents, assuming that the contents aren't longer than the width of element in which that element is floated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/89PcW/3/)

HTML:

```
<form action="">
    <fieldset>
        <button type="submit">GO</button>
        <span>
            <input type="text" />
        </span>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
fieldset {
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
button {
    float: right;
}
span {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
input {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Tested on Win7 in IE7, IE8, IE9, Opera 11, Chrome 12, FF 4, SafariWin 5.

With thanks to [thirtydot's recent revision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5589947/how-to-properly-float-two-columns-side-by-side-with-css/5590005#5590005).

Comment: I'm glad to see someone found it useful that I edited my old answers to include this method :)

Comment: thank you. I didn't realize what the combination of overflow:hidden;display:block; can provide!