# How can I have a 2 column layout with one of the columns with a fixed width and the other with the remaining width?

Tags: html, css

I have a 2 column layout. The left column has a width of 300px. I would like the right column to take up the full width of the remaining monitor space. But I just can't figure out how this mixture of px and % can be made to work? Anyone have any ideas?

I guess at worse I can use js to get the user's viewport width and add some inline styles dynamically but then I would have to perform that on every window resize, etc. So I would much rather have a pure css solution.

Comment: See [How to properly float two columns side by side with css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5589947/how-to-properly-float-two-columns-side-by-side-with-css).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer [thirtydot's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5589947/how-to-properly-float-two-columns-side-by-side-with-css/5590005#5590005):

[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qx32C/37/).

Minimum CSS requirement:

```
#sideBar {
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
}
#mainContent {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: You're right the other solution failed when I zoomed out making the resolution very small in which case the right column had a smaller than the full page's width. But this works great. I tried this before posting but had a float left on the 2nd column which was causing it to fail.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to float the fixed width column over to the left and then use a margin to simulate your other column. Something like this:

```
<div id="sidebar">
    <!-- ... -->
</div>
<div id="content">
    <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

And some CSS:

```
#sidebar {
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
}
#content {
    margin-left: 300px;
}
```

A `<div>` with its default `display:block` will naturally take up all the available width. The 300px left margin leaves an open space for the fixed width column.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/wdsbu/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible method for you: http://jsfiddle.net/mqchen/RDLMm/

Comment: Won't this method only work if the height of both columns are known and equal?