# Horizontal pull-to-refresh in HTML on iOS

Tags: css, scroll, pull-to-refresh

How can I implement [pull to refresh for iOS in HTML](http://damien.antipa.at/2012/10/16/ios-pull-to-refresh-in-mobile-safari-with-native-scrolling/) for a horizontal list?

That is, a list that scrolls horizontally, but when you pull it to the right it reveals a hidden div that can trigger a javascript callback?

Answer (score -1):

I think I've worked out a solution, but it has the odd characteristic of hiding the `.pull-to-refresh` span if I position it *completely* to the left of the scrolling content. If I position it 1px shy of all the way, however, it works fine.

Here's the [pastebin of my horizontal pull to refresh solution](http://jsfiddle.net/mhBd2/). Note that this only works on browsers that support `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch`, like those on iOS devices. You can load just the result of the jsfiddle on a mobile device here: http://fiddle.jshell.net/mhBd2/show/

Is there a better way, or did I discover a webkit bug?

For anyone else along this path, this was part of a bigger solution to get a horizontally scrolling list to dynamically fill the rest of a line (like [How to make an inline-block element fill the remainder of the line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5540485/how-to-make-an-inline-block-element-fill-the-remainder-of-the-line)), which I got working here: http://jsfiddle.net/fuWcr/