# css variable-width issues with a mock LCARS (Star Trek) just-for-fun site

Tags: css, width, expand, pixel

Just to keep my front-end web dev skills current, I decided to create a "sandbox/playpen" website based on the the fictional LCARS user interface familiar to fans of Star Trek. Here's the link.

http://www.king-con.com/sto/console/

If you take a look, you may notice that the some of the sub sections (views) have trek-ish looking headers, the basic HTML for which is:

```
<div style="display:table;width:100%">
<div style="display:table-row;">

    <div style="display:table-cell;width:15px;background-color:somecolor;border-radius:10px;">FIXED WIDTH (15px)</div>

    <div style="display:table-cell;">WIDTH VARIES WITH HEADER TEXT</div>

    <div style="display:table-cell;background-color:somecolor;border-radius:10px;>WIDTH EXPANDS TO FILL REMAINING SPACE</div>

</div>
```

ATM, I'm using a server-side function to write out those headers. It simply takes one argument (the text) and writes out the HTML based on the *character* length of the text.

You may also notice it *isn't really working*, that is it doesn't do a very precise job of guesstimating the actual *pixel-width* of the header text, and sizing the divs accordingly.

I'm wondering if there isn't a client-side, perhaps jquery-based method for precisely guaging the pixel-width of the various header captions.

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your best bet is to do all of the styling client side with CSS rather than trying to calculate the text width on the server.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
   <span class="fixed">FIXED WIDTH (110px)</span>
   <div class="varies">WIDTH VARIES WITH HEADER TEXT</div>
   <div class="right">WIDTH EXPANDS TO FILL REMAINING SPACE</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    overflow: hidden; /* clear the float */

}
.fixed {
    height: 50px;
    width: 110px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    float: left;
    border-radius:10px;
    background-color:red;
}
.varies {
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
    border-radius:10px;
    background-color:green;
}

.right {
    height: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: blue;
    border-radius:10px;
}
```

Based on this answer: [How to make an inline-block element fill the remainder of the line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5540485/how-to-make-an-inline-block-element-fill-the-remainder-of-the-line)

Fiddle Here: http://jsfiddle.net/YRDCF/

Comment: Thanks very much! That's a simple, concise solution. Heh, serves me right for forgetting what a straight up, plain-old div actually does by default. I guess I've started to overuse the newer "display:table, etc." type markup. Thanks again for the response.