# Add a long black line at the end of a header tag

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add a black line after a header tag in HTML using css :after pseudo class. Here is the code:

```css
.container {
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
  letter-spacing: 0.07em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  font-size: 130%;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
h1:after {
  display: inline-block;
  content: "";
  height: 2px;
  background: black;
  width: 200px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-top: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio quia accusamus aperiam magni perspiciatis dignissimos, reiciendis dolor temporibus esse dolores quasi, reprehenderit necessitatibus culpa quas nesciunt quaerat porro! Ab, laborum.</p>
  <p>Dolorem eligendi cumque deserunt illo quas aut pariatur inventore, optio provident maxime consectetur, soluta sed, aperiam illum beatae. Quidem beatae aliquid, impedit sit in accusamus rem necessitatibus, velit fugiat! Cupiditate.</p>
</div>
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/angelangelesiii/pen/YXwPJb

I want that long black line to span the entire width left by the header itself.

*Note: I don't want to try spanning the line to 100% then putting the header in front of it with a white background. It's an illusion but not the answer I'm trying to find. And as much as possible, no JS solutions I'm keeping this as simple as it can be.*

Comment: Not exactly what you want, because it is not CSS only, but take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5540485/how-to-make-an-inline-block-element-fill-the-remainder-of-the-line

Comment: Nevermind, I have solved my question using flexbox and pure CSS. Thanks.

Comment: The problem is that all these solutions stop working when the header is longer than one line...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `position: absolute;` and `width:100%`  will give you desired output.

Check following.

```css
.container {
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
  letter-spacing: 0.07em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  font-size: 130%;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1::after {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 black;
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    height: 2px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 8px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0.5em;
    width: 100%;
}
h1 {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio quia accusamus aperiam magni perspiciatis dignissimos, reiciendis dolor temporibus esse dolores quasi, reprehenderit necessitatibus culpa quas nesciunt quaerat porro! Ab, laborum.</p>
  <p>Dolorem eligendi cumque deserunt illo quas aut pariatur inventore, optio provident maxime consectetur, soluta sed, aperiam illum beatae. Quidem beatae aliquid, impedit sit in accusamus rem necessitatibus, velit fugiat! Cupiditate.</p>
</div>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: When I resized this one the line went too far. The line should be dynamic and should span the remaining space left.

Comment: I've also tried that one just before you edited it. It's good so I select it as the answer.

Comment: You output cuts the letter "p" tail though.

Comment: @AngelAngelesIII it's because `line-height: 1.5em;` in container.

Comment: Oops, removed as answer, the `overflow: hidden` messed up with the actual heading. It cut the "p".

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I have answered my question (once again)

```css
.container {
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
  letter-spacing: 0.07em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  font-size: 130%;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1 {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

h1:after {
  -webkit-flex: 3;
  -flex: 3;
  display: inline-block;
  content: "";
  height: 2px;
  background: black;
  margin: auto 0 auto 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio quia accusamus aperiam magni perspiciatis dignissimos, reiciendis dolor temporibus esse dolores quasi, reprehenderit necessitatibus culpa quas nesciunt quaerat porro! Ab, laborum.</p>
  <p>Dolorem eligendi cumque deserunt illo quas aut pariatur inventore, optio provident maxime consectetur, soluta sed, aperiam illum beatae. Quidem beatae aliquid, impedit sit in accusamus rem necessitatibus, velit fugiat! Cupiditate.</p>
</div>
```

I have used flexbox to solve this. I know that flexbox have some issues but this works for me so it's good.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to solve it using tables display properties

```
h1 {
 display: table;
 white-space: nowrap;
}

h1:after {
 display:table-cell;
 content: "";
 width: 100%;
 border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
```

Comment: This actually worked. Haha. I've totally overlooked `display: table;`. This is good but I've actually answered my question before, I have used flexbox instead though and the black line is peacefully centered vertically. Please see http://codepen.io/angelangelesiii/pen/YXwPJb