# Add a line from end of header text to end of container

Tags: html, css

I'm using this CSS to draw a line from the end of a header text to the end of the container:

```
h1 {
  display: flex;
}

h1::after {
  content: "";
  flex: auto;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #08A7FC;
  margin-bottom: 0.25em;
}
```

This works pretty well until the header text is longer than one line, because then the h1 takes the whole width of the container. Is there any other solution to achieve this? I already tried all the methods from [Add a long black line at the end of a header tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30116190/add-a-long-black-line-at-the-end-of-a-header-tag) but nothing works. Either the line is where it should not be or there is no line at all.

Comment: If you found the answer and it is a variation of the one you posted, why not add [mcve] to the existing answer?

Comment: "*...but nothing works* - can you clearly explain how those solutions failed?

Comment: You mean as answer to the other question?

Answer (score -1):

So, during writing this question I already found out the solution. I modified the accepted answer of [Add a long black line at the end of a header tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30116190/add-a-long-black-line-at-the-end-of-a-header-tag) by exchanging the "top" with "bottom

```
h1::after {
    background: #08A7FC;
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    height: 3px;    
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0.25em;
    width: 100%;
}
h1 {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
```