# How to get 2nd side by side div only to display bottom border

Tags: css

I just want the 2nd `div` to display a bottom border.  I either get both `div`s displaying a bottom border or none at all.

```css
.container {
  width: 75%; overflow: hidden;
  border: 0;
}
.container div:nth-child(1) {
  width: auto; float: left; height: 25px;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  background-color: white; 
}
.container div:nth-child(2) {
  margin-left: auto; height: 25px;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  background-color: ghostwhite;    
  border-bottom: 1pt solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>Div Left</div><div>Div Right</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Typo in `border-bottome`

Comment: Sorry about the typo - too late to edit... but it gives a border along the whole thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use display:inline-block, instead of float as float allows the second div to occupy space behind the first.

```css
.container {
  width: 75%;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 0;
}
.container div:nth-child(1) {
  width: auto;
  height: 25px;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  background-color: white;
  display: inline-block;
}
.container div:nth-child(2) {
  margin-left: auto;
  height: 25px;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  background-color: ghostwhite;
  border-bottom: 1pt solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>Div Left</div>
  <div>Div Right</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks.

Comment: Followup question: how do I keep the 2nd div from collapsing to the content width?

Comment: You may want to use flexbox or see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5540485/how-to-make-an-inline-block-element-fill-the-remainder-of-the-line

Comment: You are a wealth of knowledge!!  Thank you.